# How to pass int optional parameter in webmethod using C#?

Tags: c#, web-services

I am passing `int` optional parameter in webmethod but I am getting

`Cannot convert  to System.Int32.'`

my code is :

```
[WebMethod]
public string Test([Optional] int ID)
{
  return "Test";
}
```

Can you please let me know that where is the issue, and what I am missing?

Comment: How have you called this method?

Comment: Try to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

It is not possible to directly declare optional parameters in webservices.

What you can do is overloading of your methods with the MessageName attribute:

```
[WebMethod(Messagename="Test1")]
public string Test()
{
    return "Test";
}

[WebMethod(MessageName="Test2")]
public string Test(int ID)
{
    return "Test " + ID;
}
```

This is just a workaround though.

Also possible (only for primitive types):

```
[WebMethod]
public string Test()
{
    // You can grab the ID as optional parameter from the request
    int optionalID = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(this.Context.Request["optionalID"], out optionalID);

    return "Test " + optionalID;
}
```

Comment: i have used this also , and getting this error : System.ArgumentException: Cannot convert  to System.Int32.
Parameter name: type ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @vipinsinghal Can you add the code where you are calling the method? Seems like something is wrong with your call parameters.

Comment: this is asmx file, and this is test webmethod, we call it directly , u can check it , i wrote only this method, and calling directly .fyi : create asmx file, and copy above code and run that webservice , you will get issue, and if you pass string at place of int, than it's working fine. .if you really have any solution than please let me know , else as per my analysis, we can't pass optional parameter in web services ..

Comment: @vipinsinghal Ah, now I see what is your problem. Sorry for that. I edited my post to fir what you want to accomplish.